# Checking puppet-generated exim config before deploying

Tags: puppet, exim

I use Puppet to generate `/etc/exim4.conf` and I want to make sure that the configuration is valid before I install the file on production systems.

I've considered—

- **using a git hook to call `exim4 -bV -C filename`**... but this won't work because I use an ERB template to generate the file, so the end result isn't actually generated until the Puppet agent runs.  I already have a git hook to test ERB syntax.
- **letting the init script check the config file**... but this isn't good enough because, while the script will refuse to reload Exim if the configuration is invalid, the file will have already been installed and direct calls to Exim (to send mail from applications, for example) will fail.

Ideally what I want is some kind of Puppet directive that looks like

```
file { '/etc/exim4/exim4.conf':
    content => template("exim/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.erb"),
    notify => Service[exim4],
    but_before_we_install_check_syntax_with => '/usr/bin/exim4 -bV -C',
}
```

How can I check the syntax of the config file *after* it's been generated by Puppet but *before* it gets installed?

I'm using Exim 4.80 and Puppet 2.7.26 on Debian Wheezy systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing the `validate_cmd` parameter exactly. From the [Puppet type reference for `file`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-validate_cmd):

> A command for validating the file’s syntax before replacing it. If Puppet would need to rewrite a file due to new source or content, it will check the new content’s validity first. If validation fails, the file resource will fail.
>
> This command must have a fully qualified path, and should contain a percent (%) token where it would expect an input file. It must exit 0 if the syntax is correct, and non-zero otherwise. The command will be run on the target system while applying the catalog, not on the puppet master.

In your example, I think you would do this:

```
file { '/etc/exim4/exim4.conf':
    content      => template("exim/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.erb"),
    notify       => Service[exim4],
    validate_cmd => '/usr/bin/exim4 -bV -C %',
}
```

Comment: This is why I love SO.  Me: 'I wish X existed!' Answerer: 'It does, you idiot!' Me: '*blush*' :)  The only downside is that `validate_cmd` isn't there in Puppet 2.7... but I knew I needed to upgrade anyway, and this gives me a good reason to get on with it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could test the resulting configuration by using a git hook to fire up a virtual machine / container (Docker would be ideal for this) and apply the manifest in that environment.

If you're doing this regularly you might consider implementing a CI system (like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org)) which you push your changes to, have the CI run a suite of tests and on success push the changes to production.

Comment: Good answer but kind of heavyweight for my purposes -- sadly that's the kind of project I'm just never going to have time to do.  At the moment I'm just trying to mitigate against gross errors that can be picked up easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just create three tasks which just depend on each other:-

- Generate templated .conf in /tmp
- Test generated .conf
- Move .conf and notify the service

Is there a reason that this wouldn't work in this case?